# ionic serve not working properly How can I fix the error?

Tags: ionic-framework, terminal, ionic-cli

I'm a mac user while I am setting JDK environment variable on bash_profile following various blogs & articles  I have done a big mistake plz help me to fix it.

```
> Dhirajs-MacBook-Air:spiritualGuru thedkn$ ionic -v Error: EACCES:
> permission denied, mkdir 
> '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/.ionic'
> 
>     at Object.mkdirSync (fs.js:757:3)
>     at Object.mkdirpSync  (/Users/thedkn/node_modules/@ionic/utils-fs/dist/index.js:125:16)
>     at Config.set c [as c]  (/Users/thedkn/node_modules/@ionic/cli-framework/lib/config.js:37:20)
>     at Config.set (/Users/thedkn/node_modules/@ionic/cli-framework/lib/config.js:50:16)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/thedkn/node_modules/ionic/dist/index.js:72:29)
>     at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
>     at fulfilled (/Users/thedkn/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:104:62) Dhirajs-MacBook-Air:spiritualGuru thedkn$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same error on **MAC** pc. I changed file system auth only **read** to **write read** and **edit** auths.Also you can try add `sudo` in front of the `ionic serve` command.

Comment: How can I change auth status ?

Comment: Right click to folder and select give information and you can see lock icon right-down side, click this and change.